# PHP loop jump 5 characters

Tags: php

```
$field_values_array = $_REQUEST;
foreach($field_values_array as $value){
    $value = implode(",",$value);
    $value = substr_count($value,",");
    $value = $value + 1;

    $value = $value / 3;

    if($value > 0.34){
        $value_full = $value;
    }

}
foreach($field_values_array as $value){
    $value = implode(",",$value);
    for($x = 1;$x <= $value_full; $x++){
        echo mb_substr($value, 0, 5)."<br />";
    }
}
```

That's my foreach loop. `$value_full` is the amount of how many inputs there is. `Inputs / 3`

What I want my loop to do is simply: the loop shall "jump" 5  characters. Which means `0, 5` will be in loop 2: `5, 10` and so on. How can I do this?

Comment: What is in `$field_values_array`?

Comment: $field_values_array = $_REQUEST;

Comment: @mrfloden show your `$_REQUEST` value. use `print_r($_REQUEST)` to check what are the values coming.

Comment: It's $_REQUEST only, it's from 3 different inputs

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
echo mb_substr($value, 0, 5)."<br />";
```

Make 0 and 5 integers and increment them by 5 in every loop by calling them something like `$start` and `$end`:

```
echo mb_substr($value, $start, $end)."<br />";
$start +=5;
$end += 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like: `str_split`

```
$test = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla consectetur venenatis ipsum. Duis fringilla rhoncus diam a faucibus.';

var_dump(str_split($test, 5));
```

The output will be:

```
array (size=27)
  0 => string 'Lorem' (length=5)
  1 => string ' ipsu' (length=5)
  2 => string 'm dol' (length=5)
  3 => string 'or si' (length=5)
  4 => string 't ame' (length=5)
  5 => string 't, co' (length=5)
  6 => string 'nsect' (length=5)
  7 => string 'etur ' (length=5)
  8 => string 'adipi' (length=5)
  9 => string 'scing' (length=5)
  10 => string ' elit' (length=5)
  11 => string '. Nul' (length=5)
  12 => string 'la co' (length=5)
  13 => string 'nsect' (length=5)
  14 => string 'etur ' (length=5)
  15 => string 'venen' (length=5)
  16 => string 'atis ' (length=5)
  17 => string 'ipsum' (length=5)
  18 => string '. Dui' (length=5)
  19 => string 's fri' (length=5)
  20 => string 'ngill' (length=5)
  21 => string 'a rho' (length=5)
  22 => string 'ncus ' (length=5)
  23 => string 'diam ' (length=5)
  24 => string 'a fau' (length=5)
  25 => string 'cibus' (length=5)
  26 => string '.' (length=1)
```

Comment: Yes it does, but when I try to echo it out it says: Notice: Array to string conversion in. How can I fix?

Comment: foreach($test as $x){ echo $x; } ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$field_values_array = $_REQUEST; 
$sub_str_start = 0;
$sub_str_end = 5;
$limit = 5;

foreach($field_values_array as $value){
        $value = implode(",",$value);
        for($x = 1;$x <= $value_full; $x++){         
            echo mb_substr($value, $sub_str_start, $sub_str_end)."<br />";
            $sub_str_start += $limit;
            $sub_str_end   += $limit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, kind of. The only problem is that 5 becomes 10, but 0 stays 0. Which means that the first loop is 0, 5 and the second 0, 10

Comment: Same problem, but it turned out to print it as a pyramid laying down

Comment: It shall print 5 all the time, but "new 5" every time from the string

Answer (score 0):

just allow your `for` loop to increment by 5 each time and then use that value in your `mb_substr` call.

Ive used test data here as I have no idea what sort of string youre trying to process.

```
$value_full = 26;
$value = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
for($x = 0;$x <= $value_full; $x=$x+5) {
        echo mb_substr($value, $x, $x+5) . '</br>';
}
```

[Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/965ce4c27d1b1aa5f4246ee61efabae453d93632)